# Compiling a C program that uses OpenGl in Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, opengl, gcc

I am trying to compile a C program for my CS class. I have Command Line tools installed on my Mac, so I probably have OpenGL. The program description was made for Ubuntu and it says for me to compile using:

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -O2 main.o graphic.o imagem.o io.o -o ep2 -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

I ran that and it said:

```
ld: library not found for -lGL
```

What flags should I use? What do I do?

Comment: Do you really need all of `-lGL -lGLU -lglut`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In MacOS X you're not using libraries to include system level APIs, but *Frameworks*. The proper command line to compile this program would be

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -O2 \
    main.o graphic.o imagem.o io.o \
    -o ep2 \
    -framework OpenGL -lGLU -lglut
```

Note that GLU is probably part of the OpenGL framework as well. And it may be required to install GLUT first.

Comment: @ThiG.: You don't use `-lGL` on MacOS X. You use the OpenGL framework there. Oh, and in the source code you probably need to replace `#include <GL/gl.h>` with `#include <OpenGL/gl.h>`. Apple strongly suffers from *not invented here* syndrom.

Comment: +1 - I'd just add that there is also a GLUT framework available, if the OP is unfortunate enough to need it. I don't know if it plays well with core profile.

Comment: @datenwolf Thks for the reply. Although I tried the way you said and it returned `ld: library not found for -lGLU`. Any idea?

Comment: @ThiG. GLU is part of the OpenGL framework on OS X. `#include <OpenGL/glu.h>` in your source code and `-framework OpenGL` in your Makefile are all you need to use it. Likewise, there is a GLUT framework; use `#include <GLUT/glut.h>` and `-framework GLUT` on OS X. Make sure to use something like `#ifdef __APPLE__` when determining how to `#include` the headers, the rest of the world tends to follow the convention: `<GL/gl.h>` :)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thks man!! It worked perfect, no errors this time. XD

Comment: Why does it compile without any warning with `-lGL`? This is nonsense! Lost one hour on this. It works with `-framework OpenGL`.

Comment: @Bilow: Because macOS also uses to ship with a X11/GLX server and `libGL.so` (linked via `-lGL`) is the interface library required for X11/GLX execution path. So on a typical macOS system both libraries can be found, but only one of them (the one in the OpenGL framework) works through the native GUI system.

Answer (score 7):

I found you have to use

```
-framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
```

[Reference](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/courses/eecs487/glut-howto/#mac)