# How to use openGL with gcc on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, gcc

I'm trying to run [this](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/blender.c) openGL example on my Mac from command line using gcc. The XCode is installed, gcc was used many time with other programs (w\o graphics).

Following to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550265/compiling-a-c-program-that-uses-opengl-in-mac-os-x) topic I run:

```
g++ 1.cpp -framework OpenGL -lGLU -lglut
```

and get:

```
1.cpp:12:21: fatal error: GL/glut.h: No such file or directory
```

I found `glut.h` at `/System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/Headers/` and noted that structure is different (not GL folder). But even removing `GL/` and using `-I/System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/Headers`/ does not help a lot..

So I wonder - how to use openGL with gcc on Mac properly?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your first problem is that Apple's Framework infrastructure actively sabotages portability of code by placing OpenGL headers in a nonstandard path. On Apple platforms the OpenGL headers are located in a directory named `OpenGL` instead of just `GL`.

So to portably include the headers you have to write

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#else
#include <GL/gl.h>
#endif
```

Your other problem is, that GLUT is not part of OpenGL and an independent, third party library, that's no longer contained within the OpenGL framework. You need to use the GLUT Framework. And of course that one uses nonstandard include paths as well:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
```

Compile with the `-framework OpenGL -framework GLUT` options.

Answer (score 5):

On mavericks using the include

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

works if you compile with the following line

```
g++ 1.cpp -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**1. Make sure you've included the required libraries**

- Click on the project name on Project navigator -> go to Build Phases
- Expand `Link Binary with Libraries` -> click the '+' button and select the following frameworks:
  [image]

**2. Change the include statements**

- `#include <GLUT/glut.h>`

**3. Get rid of deprecation warnings**

- `#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION` // use this to get rid of the deprecation warnings