# Error when compiling OpenGL program on MacOSX ('ld: library not found for -lopengl32')

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

When I try to compile a program using OpenGL on MacOSX I get the error message 'ld: library not found for -lopengl32' and 'clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)', which I'm guessing is caused by the library not being found. The code works on Windows, but not on Mac. I'm using CodeBlocks 13.12.

I have tried to install OpenGL using the commands

```
brew install glfw3
```

and

```
brew install glew
```

but I still get the same error.

I have tried this on a Windows system and there it works out of the box.

What do I need to do to install the missing library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling a C program that uses OpenGl in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550265/compiling-a-c-program-that-uses-opengl-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opengl32` is the name of the API library on *Windows*. On macOS you have to use `-framework OpenGL` instead of `-lopengl32`. And for reference, on Linux it's either `-lGL` (linking to the traditional LSB defined `libGL.so`) or `-lOpenGL` (linking against GLVND).