# OpenGL/glu.h file not found

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, glew, glu

I am trying to build a project on QtCreator and initially I couldn't run it due to Xcode (having to agree to the new Xcode license), but after having accepted it, I now get the error:

```
In file included from .../libs/glew-1.10.0/src/glew.c:32:
'OpenGL/glu.h' file not found
```

The code giving the error is:

```
#ifndef GLEW_NO_GLU
#/* this is where we can safely include GLU */
#  if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
#    include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#  else
#    include <GL/glu.h>
#  endif
#endif
```

I checked and `glu.h` normally exists in `/Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platforms/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glu.h`.

(I'm running on MacOS Mojave 10.14.5)

Any idea what is wrong here? Thanks!

**EDIT: Turns out it was still an Xcode issue and was fixed using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320677/error-could-not-resolve-sdk-path-for-macosx10-8%60).**

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18550734/3871028), specially for the "framekork" flag.. Anyhow, `glew` is not needed in Apple, it's harmless though.